# c++ libtomcrypt library outputting shorter hashes/truncated hashes

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha, truncation, libtomcrypt

I am trying to generate hashes to use in a blockchain project, when looking for a crypto library i stumbled accross tomcrypt and chose to download it since it was easy to install, but now i have a problem, when I create the hashes (btw i'm usign SHA3_512 but the bug is present in every other SHA hashing algorithm) sometimes it outputs the correct hash but truncated

photo example
[Hash truncating example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRKfX.png)

this is the code for the hashing function

```
string hashSHA3_512(const std::string& input) {
//Initial
unsigned char* hashResult = new unsigned char[sha3_512_desc.hashsize];
//Initialize a state variable for the hash
hash_state md;
sha3_512_init(&md);
//Process the text - remember you can call process() multiple times
sha3_process(&md, (const unsigned char*) input.c_str(), input.size());
//Finish the hash calculation
sha3_done(&md, hashResult);
// Convert to string
string stringifiedHash(reinterpret_cast<char*>(hashResult));
// Return the result
return stringToHex(stringifiedHash);
}
```

and here is the code for the toHex function even if I already checked and the truncating hash problem pops up before this function is called

```
string stringToHex(const std::string& input)

{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    std::string output;
    output.reserve(input.length() * 2);
    for (unsigned char c : input)
    {
        output.push_back(hex_digits[c >> 4]);
        output.push_back(hex_digits[c & 15]);
    }

return output;
}
```

if someone has knowledge about this library or in general about this problem and possible fixes pls explain to me, i'm stuck from 3 days

*UPDATE*
I figured out the program is truncating the hashes when it encounters 2 consecutive zeros in hex so 8 zeros in binary (or simply 2 bytes) but I still don't understand why, if you do pls let me and hopefully other people with the same problem know

Comment: You have **zero** ideas why the C-like character string would be cut short?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes unfortunately not yet, i'm working on it, I really hope the problem is in my code because I'm very bad at installing c++ libraries

Comment: Ah, sorry, but `reinterpret_cast<char*>(hashResult)` gives you a C string, which will stop at the first zero character. I hoped that the hint would be enough.